# Add NSMutableDictionary into Array for Button Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have one NSMutableDictionary:

```
sampleDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[sampleDict setObject:@"FooIndex" forKey:@"Key_1"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FooOne" forKey:@"Key_2"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FooTwo" forKey:@"Key_3"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FoFour" forKey:@"Key_4"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FooFivve" forKey:@"Key_5"]; // adds @"Foo"
```

I want add this dictionary into Array on Button action here code like this,

```
arraytesting = [NSMutableArray new];

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
    [arraytesting addObject:sampleDict];
    NSLog(@"Sample arraytesting>>>>> %@",arraytesting);

}
```

Finally the output is:

```
(
        {
        "Key_1" = FooIndex;
        "Key_2" = FooOne;
        "Key_3" = FooTwo;
        "Key_4" = FoFour;
        "Key_5" = FooFivve;
    }
)
```

But when I need to update the dictionary:

```
[sampleDict setObject:@"one" forKey:@"Key_1"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"two" forKey:@"Key_2"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"three" forKey:@"Key_3"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FoFour" forKey:@"Key_4"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FooFivve" forKey:@"Key_5"]; // adds @"Foo"
```

The output looks like:

```
(
    {
        "Key_1" = FooIndex;
        "Key_2" = FooOne;
        "Key_3" = FooTwo;
        "Key_4" = FoFour;
        "Key_5" = FooFivve;
    },
    {
        "Key_1" = FooIndex;
        "Key_2" = FooOne;
        "Key_3" = FooTwo;
        "Key_4" = FoFour;
        "Key_5" = FooFivve;
    }
)
```

And I want the output to be like:

```
(
    {
        "Key_1" = FooIndex;
        "Key_2" = FooOne;
        "Key_3" = FooTwo;
        "Key_4" = FoFour;
        "Key_5" = FooFivve;
    },
    {
        "Key_1" = one;
        "Key_2" = two;
        "Key_3" = three;
        "Key_4" = FoFour;
        "Key_5" = FooFivve;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To array you add reference to object. After that, you edit you dictionary and add it reference again. You can call `copy` to make new instance of sampleDict. 
You method must be like this:

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender { [arraytesting addObject:[sampleDict copy]]; NSLog(@"Sample arraytesting>>>>> %@",arraytesting); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PRECover but same problem faced

Answer (score 0):

```
[sampleDict setObject:@"one" forKey:@"Key_1"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"two" forKey:@"Key_2"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"three" forKey:@"Key_3"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FoFour" forKey:@"Key_4"]; // adds @"Foo"
[sampleDict setObject:@"FooFivve" forKey:@"Key_5"]; // adds @"Foo"
```

Here you are using same reference of same sampleDict. Instead of that create a new Object again and add.

`smapleDict = [NSMutableArray new]`

```
[sampleDict setObject:@"one" forKey:@"Key_1"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [sampleDict setObject:@"two" forKey:@"Key_2"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [sampleDict setObject:@"three" forKey:@"Key_3"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [sampleDict setObject:@"FoFour" forKey:@"Key_4"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [sampleDict setObject:@"FooFivve" forKey:@"Key_5"]; // adds @"Foo"
```

Comment: i didn't understand @sivajee

Comment: You are making changes to same dictionary. That'y you are getting same elements

Comment: here i want use only one dictionary,no need to create another one

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary `sampleDict` is an reference so you need to mutable copy of it, if you don't and you modify the original dictionary, this will modify all your dicts on your array, so you need copy, modify and add then to your Array, something like this

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property NSMutableArray * arrayTesting;
@property NSMutableDictionary * sampleDict;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.sampleDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];


    [self.sampleDict setObject:@"FooIndex" forKey:@"Key_1"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [self.sampleDict setObject:@"FooOne" forKey:@"Key_2"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [self.sampleDict setObject:@"FooTwo" forKey:@"Key_3"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [self.sampleDict setObject:@"FoFour" forKey:@"Key_4"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [self.sampleDict setObject:@"FooFivve" forKey:@"Key_5"]; // adds @"Foo"

    self.arrayTesting = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self.arrayTesting addObject:self.sampleDict];
    NSLog(@"Sample arraytesting>>>>> %@",self.arrayTesting);
}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {



    NSMutableDictionary * toModify = [self.sampleDict mutableCopy];

    [toModify setObject:@"One" forKey:@"Key_1"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [toModify setObject:@"Two" forKey:@"Key_2"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [toModify setObject:@"Three" forKey:@"Key_3"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [toModify setObject:@"FoFour" forKey:@"Key_4"]; // adds @"Foo"
    [toModify setObject:@"FooFivve" forKey:@"Key_5"]; // adds @"Foo"

    [self.arrayTesting addObject:toModify];
    NSLog(@"Sample arraytesting>>>>> %@",self.arrayTesting);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks @ reinier ,It's Just one Time update ,but here i want update new values on dictionary every button action

Comment: Its the same, change the values in a new mutable copy of your dictionary and then add to your array

Comment: You are getting data from what? can you post all your viewController code in order to understand what are you trying?